# Deleting Buttons when another Button has been clicked

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have been working on a POS system using `VB.NET` and needed some help figuring out a solution to a problem I am facing.
Basically, I use a function which uses an `SQL` table to find informations related to the items which should correspond to a certain category which lies in the form as a `Button`.

Essentially, all the categories are automatically created onto the `Form` using the `SQL` table.

I want to find a way using which I will be able to display items in the form of `Buttons` assigned to each category in the DataBase which has already been done in the code.
The only problem is that the old items in the form of buttons wont get deleted and will stay on the screen causing a problem where I am not able to see the newer items being called by the category `Button`.

I have an example of the code below:

```vb
Public Sub Form13_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim point As Integer
    Dim point1 As Integer
    point = 20
    point1 = 100

    Label2.Text = Form12.selected_value
    Dim connection As New MySqlConnection
    connection.ConnectionString = ("host=localhost;user=root;password=;database=pos;")
    connection.Open()
    Dim command As New MySqlCommand("select * from categories", connection)
    Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
    reader = command.ExecuteReader
    Dim perm As String
    While reader.Read()
        Dim button As New Button

        Dim value As String = reader.GetString("category_name")
        perm = reader.GetString("category_name")
        button.Name = value
        button.Text = value
        button.Height = 50
        button.Width = 190
        button.Font = New Font("arial", 11)
        button.Location = New Point(point, point1)
        Me.Controls.Add(button)
        point1 = point1 + 50

        'showing items based on the button that the user clicks
        AddHandler button.Click,
        Sub()
            reader.Close()
            Dim command1 As New MySqlCommand("select * from items where category=@name", connection)
            command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", value)
            reader = command1.ExecuteReader

            'new look for the items to be converted into physical buttons
            Dim point2 As Integer
            Dim point3 As Integer

            point2 = 235
            point3 = 100
            Dim counter As Integer
            counter = 1
            While reader.Read()
                Dim item As String
                Dim category_type As String
                category_type = reader.GetString("category")
                item = reader.GetString("name")

                Dim button1 As New Button
                button1.Name = item
                button1.Text = item
                button1.Height = 50
                button1.Width = 160
                button1.Font = New Font("Arial", 11)
                button1.Location = New Point(point2, point3)
                Me.Controls.Add(button1)
                counter = counter + 1
                Me.Refresh()

                'figure out how to remove buttons when they are not neeeded aka find a way to check when a button is being clicked
                If point2 > 700 Then
                    point2 = 235
                    point3 = point3 + 55
                Else
                    point2 = point2 + 168
                End If
            End While
        End Sub
    End While
End Sub
```

Please help me because I have been stuck with this problem for quite some time.
I assume it can be solved by finding out when the user clicks on a different category so the previous items placed on the form can be disposed using `button1.Dispose`.

An image of the table containing the items has been attached below:

[image: image of table containing items]

Comment: Since you are generating the controls from the database, and you know the category at that time, why not create a Dictionary(Of String, List(Of Control)) where the key is the category? Then when you want to get rid of all controls related to a particular category you can just go through the list and remove them from the form?

Comment: Alternatively, if you only want to display particular categories at a time, modify your query to only search for particular categories. Then clear all controls before performing a new query, or all controls in a given container, etc.

Comment: @Ryan Pierce Williams Is there any possible way using which I can find when the user clicks on a different category so that based on the user clicking on a different category I can clear the current item buttons displaying before the next items for the category clicked appear?

Comment: Just stick the logic in your click handler for the category button

Comment: @Ryan Pierce Williams Is there anyway for me to make the button1 variable global so I can access it before its actual assignment or from a different function so it can be disposed everytime the loop cycle starts ?

Comment: As a matter of good programming practice, avoid globals. Use a singleton if it is appropriate, or a thread static variable, or even better a local class variable, but not a global. I don't know what all your code looks like, so it's difficult to give you overly specific advise on exactly how I'd do it in your situation. However, you can certainly use a variable to keep track of such information - and in fact it is good practice to store such data in variables or object so that they can be accessed outside of the UI thread.

Comment: @Ryan Pierce Williams I understand what you mean but as shown in my code above I have the need to globalise the button1 variable so I can access it and delete it before the start of the next loop cycle or press of another button on the categories

Comment: The load code should all execute before you have an opportunity to click any button (being performed in the UI thread).

Comment: I would also take the click handler routine and move it outside of the load routine as its own proper function

Comment: @ Ryan Pierce Williams I have resolved the problem by putting all the item buttons into a groupbox and clearing them each time a button for different category has been clicked through the relevant handler which helped me resolve the problem. Thanks for the help anyway.